# Issues with Codeigniter and Cron Bootstrapper

Tags: codeigniter, cron

I am trying to create a cron job while taking advantage of my current CI setup and the use of Controllers and Models. I am using Cron Bootstrapper (http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Cron_job_bootstrapper/) because it gives me easy access to test the process locally on-demand or be available as a traditional cron process on a server. I can reach the controller using the bootstrapper file and the command line, however, I am getting many different error messages or alerts depending on how I set up my controller.

If I keep the controller as it should be with `parent::Controller();`, I get the following message:

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

The error is coming from the DB_driver.php `initialize()` method.

If I remove the call to `parent::Controller()` from the controller then I get the following alert:

```
    <p>Severity: Warning</p>
    <p>Message:  date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You
       are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
       date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
       methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled
       the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for
       'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead</p>
    <p>Filename: htdocs/cron.php</p>
    <p>Line Number: 122</p>`
```

By removing the `parent::Controller();` I am not able to access any models via `$this->load->model('model');` and I get the following message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function model() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_site/system/application/controllers/cron.php on line 9

Any info that will allow me to use the bootstrapper file with CI will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set **$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;** in your database config file to enable more verbose error reporting.
2. **You need to heed the timezone warning and set a default in your php.ini file**. This is a new requirement as of PHP 5.3. If you are running on a shared server and do not have access to php.ini, you can either request that your web host set a default value, or you can try setting it manually using ini_set() at the top of your bootstrap file.
3. **Check and see if your database config file is being loaded, and if so, double-check your database connection settings**. If the settings are right, there could be a firewall blocking you, or the database user you are connecting with might not have permission to access the database you are trying to use.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon. #1 was already set. #2 was also set, but MAMP overrides it (I fixed it with `date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");`. In my search to check #3 I found it was all correct as well, but found another user that had the same issue. Changing the path to PHP did the trick. Thanks again.